# Check if a Column Exists and Add it When Doesn't Exist

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

In the Azure Data Factory data mapping flow, is there a way to check if a column `Date` exists in the input file? If `true`, select the `Date` column, if not then create a `Date` column but leave the column blank in the output?

I tried with conditional `select` that `if name=='Date'`, name the column as `Date`, but it the workflow fail with the "Date" column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `byName()` in the derived column transformation.

This is my sample input data with `Date` column.

[image]

In derived column, use the below dataflow expression.

```
toDate(byName('Date'))
```

[image]

**The above `byName()` will search for the given column name and if it is there in the columns list then it gives those values and if it not there it will give null values to the column.**

**Result when Date column present in source:**

[image]

**Source without `Date` column:**

[image]

**Result with `Date` column and values as `NULL`:**

[image]

After derived column transformation, use select transformation to select your desired columns.

Comment: Thank you! That's really clear and helpful!